# How to add journal rules using power shell

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, rules, journal

Is there a way of adding undeliverable journal reports which is in Microsoft Purview >  Data life cycle management > Exchange (legacy) > settings > undeliverable reports using powershell?

And at the same time adding a new journal rule which is applied to all messages and everyone in the organisation?

Everything. I’ve lost the will to live.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.